# How to merge feeds using the SyndicationFeed class?

Tags: c#, xml, rss, syndicationfeed

I'm wondering how to merge several RSS feeds using the SyndicationFeed class?

Comment: Have you tried `var joinedFeeds = syndicationFeed1.Items.Concat(syndicationFeed2.Items)` ?

Comment: This doesn't work: `public static SyndicationFeed MergeFeeds(SyndicationFeed sf1, SyndicationFeed sf2){
            sf1.Items.Concat(sf2.Items);
            return sf1;
        }`

Comment: Because it must be `public static IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> MergeFeeds(SyndicationFeed sf1, SyndicationFeed sf2) { return sf1.Items.Concat(sf2.Items); }`

Comment: I will try it but can I convert the IEnumerable<SyndicationItem> into SyndicationFeed? Because I need a SyndicationFeed as return...

Comment: I will try: `public static SyndicationFeed MergeFeeds(SyndicationFeed sf1, SyndicationFeed sf2)
        {
            return (SyndicationFeed)sf1.Items.Concat(sf2.Items);
        }`

Comment: As expected: _Unable to cast object of type '<ConcatIterator>d__71`1[System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem]' to type 'System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed'_.

Comment: When I do your trick it returns a new SyndicationFeed with Items as {System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator<System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationItem>}